# Adding dynamic shortcode to dynamic link on wordpress?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, contextual-help

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

I would like to make this link open a messages page, where the better-messages plugin is installed, the page would open with the users name already selected on the email recipient. It requires short code and can't seem to find the help from other support groups helpful.
[image]

Thank you